# Managing task lists

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I would like to create a general task list.  This list could apply to one or several C# files.  I wish I could create a Readme.txt and have:

```
//TODO: Controller/Action1 and Controller/Action2 should have input that looks like a div
//TODO: Some funky thing
//TODO: blah
```

However, this is not picked up by the Task List window.  Instead I have a `generalNotes.cs` file that contains a list of various TODO's.  This way I can see the results in my task list window.    Putting this into an empty `.cs` file just feels a little silly.  Is there any built in support for tracking general tasks?

Comment: Can someone explain why this is not a constructive question?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any built in support for tracking general tasks?

I don't know if there is a general way, but if you want to continue using a text file inside your project:

1. Right click your tasks text file
2. Choose Properties
3. In the "Build Action" dropdown select "Compile"

Your `TODOs` will now appear in your task list under the Comments drop down.

EDIT TO ADD: This works on VS2012 Ultimate. Other versions, YMMV.

Comment: VS 2012 Premium this does not work.  Option is greyed out.

Comment: Seems weird that would be an "Ultimate" only feature. Perhaps there is something else going on.

Comment: I agree it is a strange feature to be reserved for Ultimate only..?  My project is an MVC4 and the debugger is off.